# Placing $4n$ non-attaking queens of in a $4n \times 4n$ chessboard.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

Is it possible to place $4n$ non-attaking queens of in a $4n \times 4n$ chessboard??

I have found that it can be done for $4 \times 4$ chess board and trying to extend it to $8 \times 8$ chessboard and then apply induction.

I also see that we cannot place the queens in the corner position of a board!!

Will this process work?? and how please help!!

Comment: Why are you limiting this to $4n\times 4n$ boards? It's a fairly well known problem.

Comment: can you please quote the problem??

Comment: http://penguin.ewu.edu/~trolfe/QueenLasVegas/Hoffman.pdf

Comment: i think for this problem the solution will be unique!!

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) and a [Java applet demonstration](http://www.math.utah.edu/~alfeld/queens/queens.html).  This is usually considered a problem of combinatorial search.

Comment: can you tell why we cannot place any queen in any corner of a board??

Comment: @tone, the Wikipedia article linked by hardmath shows solutions which *do* place a queen in a corner of the board.

Comment: This [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229040/) may prove useful reading.